# Not enough data to fill buffer

Tags: parachain, rust

When running an API function using rust, we get this error:

`GenericError { reason: "Failed to get unsigned proposals: FailedToDecodeReturnValue { function: \"DKGApi_get_unsigned_proposals\", error: Error { cause: None, desc: \"Not enough data to fill buffer\" } }" }`

What could be causing this?

**Background**

Repository: https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate

Host OS: Mac Ventura

CPU: Mac M1

Substrate: `0.9.39`

Executed in repository root with: `./scripts/run-standalone.sh --clean`

Error raised at: https://github.com/webb-tools/dkg-substrate/blob/a1ac55ae6d8b8218aceef3731a1c3567af29b302/dkg-gadget/src/signing_manager/mod.rs#L101

Comment: This Issue might help you https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/399